# case when statement after select not working in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I try to do something like this

```
    SET parentid = (SELECT parent FROM pages WHERE id = pageid);
    CASE WHEN ( parentid <> 0 ) THEN
      SET mainid = (SELECT parent FROM pages WHERE id = parentid);
    ELSE 
      SET mainid = 0;
    END
```

But for some reason I get

> Syntax error near 'CASE WHEN ( parentid <> 0 ) THEN SET mainid =
>   (SELECT parent FROM pages WHERE ' at line 3

What am I missing?

Comment: probably you are missing with `;` after `(SELECT parent FROM pages WHERE id = pageid)`

Comment: Nope, that's not the point

Comment: Are you working with a client that requires you to set the `DELIMITER` when defining a multi-statement SP?

Comment: No I don't need to do that

Comment: Without the full context of the procedure you're defining, it's hard to see how this is being used. Why not `IF/ELSE` instead of `CASE` (which is more at home inside a `SELECT` or `UPDATE` than in SP flow control)

Comment: I tried IF/ELSE and got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `END CASE` clause and missing semicolon at the end:

```
CASE WHEN ( parentid <> 0 ) THEN
      SET mainid = (SELECT parent FROM pages WHERE id = parentid);
    ELSE 
      SET mainid = 0;
END CASE;
```

Please read documentation for proper syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html 

Here is link to a working demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9495d1/2

Comment: @Johnny000  Sir, I see only `END` without `CASE` in the question. Could be that my glasses are broken and I can't see it. However I've checked my code and it compiles and works fine, please take a look at this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9495d1/2

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this doesn't need variables...

```
SELECT CAST(CASE
    WHEN id = pageid AND parent = 0
    THEN 0
    ELSE (SELECT parent FROM pages WHERE id = parentid)
END AS INTEGER) AS mainid
FROM pages
```